# Why servers error log states lots of file doesn't exist, but files are accessible and website works well

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404, centos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why servers error log states lots of file doesn't exist, but files are accessible and website works well](https://serverfault.com/questions/302479/why-servers-error-log-states-lots-of-file-doesnt-exist-but-files-are-accessibl)

we migrated our website onto VPS server (CentOS 5.6 + Plesk 9.5), everything works nice, but one strange thing that i noticed in Plesk, is error_log file, most of the time it filled up with hundreds entries like:

```
...
[Thu Aug 10 11:35:48 2011] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/yourdomain.com/httpdocs/category1
[Thu Aug 10 11:35:48 2011] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/yourdomain.com/httpdocs/category2
....
```

If i open those urls `(ex. http://yourdomain.com/category2)` in my web browser everything works well, no 404 error, headers response 200 so everything works as should and i see page that i wanted. But why log file see it as an error and states that file is not exist? Also i want to mention that "category1", "category2" is not physical directories, it's .htacess and mod_rewrite managed paths, so not real folders.

mod_rewrite seems not to properly tell to the log system that the request should not be considered as a 404 when it looks like a file/folder that doesn't exist physically but handled by mod_rewrite.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Tim

Comment: Question belongs to a webmaster forum, I can't see any link to programming here, therefore voted for migration.

Comment: Probably you're right, i worte it here thinking maybe it's .htaccess fault. Reposted it at Serversfault.

Answer (score 0):

If those are .htaccess rules as you said, please make sure Apachs is actually reading the .htaccess - this can be done for example by adding a line in your .htaccess like

deny from all

then trying to access the website.. if you can still connect, means that apache is NOT reading the .htaccess at all.

To make it readable, go to the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and change the AllowOverride and Options for the correspondent directory to allow parsing .htaccess files, all should go like knife in butter ;)